# ArcGIS 10.2 Copy attributes between polygon layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have two polygons layers (countries). One contains attributes. The second one was created from lines so does not have attributes, and is not exactly similar to the first one (some countries outlines have been updated).

How do I transfer the attributes from my old countries layer to the new one?

Answer (score 4):

1. Convert your old layer to point with tool "Feature to point", dont forget to activate inside option.
2. Second create a "spatial join" from new polygon layer to layer point created in first step.
3. Review you final data. On new layer created in step 2 will be a field "Distance" inspect the row that have a big number, with which point it has been joined, if any error occurred repair it manually.